# Chutes and Ladder determine if cell is empty

Tags: java, methods

i am making a Chutes Ladder program and needed another way to determine if the Cell is a empty space beside the 3 spaces i am using. Is there any other way to determine the Cell is empty beside if the cell have 3 spaces.

Cell.java:

```
public class Cell {
    String text;
    int number;

    public Cell() {}

    public Cell( String r ) {
        text = r;
    }

    public Cell( int m, String r ) {
        text = r;
        number = m;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText( String x ) {
        text = x;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setText( int x ) {
        number = x;
    }

    public boolean isLadder() {
        return (text.equals( "L" ));
    }

    public boolean isChute() {
        return (text.equals( "C" ));
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return text.equals( "   " );
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        if ( isChute() )
            s = s + text + Math.abs( number );
        else if ( isLadder() )
            s = s + text + number;
        else if ( isEmpty() )
            s = s + "   ";
        return s;
    }
}
```

ChutesAndLadders.java

```
public class ChutesAndLadders {

    Cell[] board;
    Random ran = new Random();

    public ChutesAndLadders() {}

    public ChutesAndLadders( int numChutes, int numLadders ) {
        board = new Cell[100];
        for ( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) {
            board[i] = new Cell( "   " );
        }
        chutes( numChutes );
        ladders( numLadders );
    }

    public void setBoard( Cell[] board ) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public Cell[] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void makeChutes( int x ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < x; i++ ) {
            int temp = ran.nextInt( board.length );
            if ( board[temp].isEmpty() )
                board[temp] = new Cell( -10, "C" );
            else
                i--;
        }
    }

    public void makeLadders( int y ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < y; i++ ) {
            int temp = ran.nextInt( board.length );
            if ( temp < 10 )
                temp = ran.nextInt( board.length );
            if ( board[temp].isEmpty() )
                board[temp] = new Cell( 10, "L" );
            else
                i--;
        }
    }

    public void chutes( int x ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < x; i++ ) {
            int temp = ran.nextInt( board.length );
            if ( board[temp].isEmpty() )
                board[temp] = new Cell( -10, "C" );
            else
                i--;
        }
    }

    public void ladders( int y ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < y; i++ ) {
            int temp = ran.nextInt( board.length );
            if ( temp < 10 )
                temp = ran.nextInt( board.length );
            if ( board[temp].isEmpty() )
                board[temp] = new Cell( 10, "L" );
            else
                i--;
        }
    }

    public int addToMove( String a ) {
        if ( a.equals( "C10" ) ) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt( a.substring( 1 ) );
            return n;
        }
        if ( a.equals( "L10" ) ) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt( a.substring( 1 ) );
            return n * -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        int counter = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) {
            counter++;
            System.out.print( "|" + board[i] );
            if ( counter == 10 ) {
                System.out.print( "|" + "\n" );
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

test.java:

```
public class test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ChutesAndLadders cl = new ChutesAndLadders( 10, 10 );
        cl.makeChutes( 5 );
        cl.makeLadders( 5 );
        int chutes = 0, ladders = 0;
        for ( Cell cell : cl.getBoard() ) {
            if ( cell.isLadder() )
                ladders++;
            else if ( cell.isChute() )
                chutes++;
        }
        System.out.println( "Board has " + chutes + " chutes and " + ladders + " ladders" );
        cl.printBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: When do **you** consider the cell to be `empty`?  You can set its String to `null`, for example.   If your question is: how to determine if a String contains only `white space`, then you can use something like `str.trim().length() == 0` condition.

Comment: you could use the empty string `""`.  if you did that, you could even use the `String.isEmpty()` method to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
        return !(isLadder() && isChute());
}
```